# Why percent values in CSS translates are relative to the element itself?

Tags: css

It's well known that percent values in CSS translations are relative to the size of the translated element itself while (AFAIK) applied to any other property they're relative to parent's size. This has been largely used to center elements vertically, for example, way before `flexbox` or `grid` were a thing in our browsers.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#element {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

In this example we see how 50% applied to `left` and `top` properties refers to 50% of `.wrapper`'s width (or height, for `top`), so it's 250px and 100px, respectively. But in `translate` -50% is applied to the `#element` itself, so it's 50% of 42px.

I see the benefits of it, but I don't understand the reasons for this (apparent) incoherence. So,

1. Why percent values in CSS translates are relative to the element itself while in any other property are relative to parent's size?
2. Are there any other properties with this behaviour?

**EDIT:** As stated in SergeS' answer, I see in MDN that all properties have *by definition* their own references for `<percentage>` values.

In `transform`,

> Percentages – refer to the size of bounding box.

In `top`,

> Percentages – refer to the height of the containing block.

In `margin`,

> Percentages – refer to the width of the containing block.

I'm curious about the reasons for those definitions.

Comment: translate property works on the elements as it does not involve redrawing of pixels on the browser and it is just moving from one place to another. Other properties for this will include all transform properties I suppose.

Comment: Thank you @ShubhamAgrawal. Do you know any source for this *redrawing pixels* theory?

Comment: You can refer to [https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count]

Answer (score 1):

1. - Translate = take current element and translate by definition. So it takes current elemnt into account
   - left, top, ... - and others *position* properties - they define how the element is positioned in parent element - thus, they calculate position to offset parent (parent element for relative, nearest relative / absolute / fixed element for absolute)
   - padding, margin, ... - and othet *box model* properties - they define how the element is sized inside parent element - so again they are related to parent container
2. No

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `translate` taking the element itself for reference **by definition** seems a pretty good reason to explain that behaviour. I'd like to know *why*...

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, values are related to the element itself.

In the first case, when you say `left:50%` and `top:50%` it just means to keep the element at 50% offset from the top and left by measuring the offset from the first relatively positioned parent (default body).

In the second case, when you say translate it means you are transforming the element by translate method with the given values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I must say I don't really get it. I'm using 50% in multiple properties of `#element`, e.g. in x-axis, `left` 50% takes the value 250px but in the x-coordinate for `translate` in takes the value 21px, so obviously the reference is not the same. Also, I don't see how the second case affects the size of the element...